# PLS-907 cannot load library unit

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Following is my oracle version
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

I was trying to alter a table to add a column but since it took long time, i cancelled it.

After sometime, i started seeing errors in all packages and views that referenced the unit.
Error message is

> PLS-907: cannot load library unit (table name)

Googling on this error does not give much information. In one place, i saw that below command will help but it seems to me as very risky command

> alter system flush shared_pool

Can anyone help me with the reason and solution to this?

Thanks,
Jeevan

Comment: Sounds like maybe your table is in a weird state and the packages that refer to it can't recompile. Not sure how flushing would have any effect, but I'm not sure I'd say it's dangerous. Does describing your table show the new column, and does anything look amiss in `user_tables`?

Comment: New column is not added and in user_tables says the status as VALID

Comment: @Alex - it might also be a weird case when the dictionary is not in sync with the actual table so flushing the dictionary pool might help. since this problem is not reproducible in a test environment i think you should try droop and recreate the table and not flush your pool.

Comment: Is there a database link involved?

Comment: check this Oracle note "PLS-00907: Cannot Load Library Unit" Error With Object Name Or Finding Mismatch Timestamp Between The Parent And The Dependent Objects (Doc ID 2259160.1)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

it happens because of DB links are dropped and recreated for connections so just recompiling the package will resolve this and some times it automatically recompile it .

Answer (score 0):

While changing the length of a varchar2 may resolve a problem in one procedure, for example, it can cause other objects to go invalid.  Typically the solution for resolving the invalid object is just recompiling.  Before recompiling - parameters, variables, etc need to be checked to ensure they accommodate for the change.